# Build with proguard stuck at "Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]" from last 23 hr to sign apk

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

i am using ProGuard to minify and build signed apk. but it taking to long time to build the apk and not completed yet. it stuck at "Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]" from last 23 hr. i tried "-Keep" and "-dontwarn" commands with all external lib. still it is not finishing the process and nor throwing any error.

here is my proGuard-rules.pro content.

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn in.myProject.**
-dontwarn com.woxthebox.draglistview.**
-dontwarn com.android.support.appcompat-v7.**
-dontwarn com.android.support.support-v4.**
-dontwarn com.android.support.design.**
-dontwarn com.mcxiaoke.volley.library.**
-dontwarn com.google.code.gson.gson.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.android-times-square.**
-dontwarn com.github.woxthebox.draglistview.**
-dontwarn com.android.support.recyclerview-v7.**
-keep class com.woxthebox.draglistview.** { *; }
-keep interface com.woxthebox.draglistview.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.support.appcompat-v7.**{*;}
-keep interface com.android.support.appcompat-v7.**{*;}
-keep class com.android.support.support-v4.**{*;}
-keep interface com.android.support.support-v4.**{*;}
-keep class com.android.support.design.**{*;}
-keep interface com.android.support.design.**{*;}
-keep class com.mcxiaoke.volley.library.**{*;}
-keep interface com.mcxiaoke.volley.library.**{*;}
-keep class com.google.code.gson.gson.**{*;}
-keep interface com.google.code.gson.gson.**{*;}
-keep class com.squareup.android-times-square.**{*;}
-keep interface com.squareup.android-times-square.**{*;}
-keep class com.github.woxthebox.draglistview.**{*;}
-keep interface com.github.woxthebox.draglistview.**{*;}
-keep class com.android.support.recyclerview-v7.**{*;}
-keep interface com.android.support.recyclerview-v7.**{*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.play-services-gcm.**{*;}
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.play-services-gcm.**{*;}
```

and here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Debug'
            keyPassword 'xyz'
            storeFile file('.app/XXXXX.jks')
            storePassword 'XCV'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.myProject"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 21
        versionName "0.21"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
    compile 'com.github.woxthebox:draglistview:1.2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    /*compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+"*/

}
```

The Error occurred while running pro-guard with default pro-guard file

```
Error:15:24:43.753 [ERROR] [system.err] Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
15:24:43.753 [ERROR] [system.err]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
15:24:44.284 [ERROR] [system.err] Warning: org.acra.ErrorReporter: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
15:24:45.444 [ERROR] [system.err] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
15:24:45.444 [ERROR] [system.err]          You probably need to update the library versions.
15:24:45.444 [ERROR] [system.err]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
15:24:45.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:24:45.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:24:45.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:24:45.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:24:45.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
15:24:45.446 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
15:24:45.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:24:45.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:24:45.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
15:24:45.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
15:24:45.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
15:24:45.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
15:24:45.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
15:24:45.447 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
15:24:45.448 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
15:24:45.449 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.awaitRethrowExceptions(Job.java:79)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:209)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
15:24:45.450 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 70 more
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:52)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:273)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:62)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:199)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:51)
15:24:45.451 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
15:24:45.452 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:223)
15:24:45.452 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Comment: just try to sign your apk using default proguard file, and please let me know warnings in that case.

Comment: @RahulSharma see my edit contain error with default pro-guard files

Comment: are you using libs file in your project?

Comment: the issue is solved by updating acra lib to 4.9.0

Comment: so now your signed apk is ready?

Comment: yes the apk is signed perfectly and working fne

Answer (score 1):

This issue occur with older version of arca lib which use apache http client. but Apache http is removed from android API 23 so that its required to update Acra lib to version 4.9.0 so that pro-guard should run properly with acra on API 23.

Comment: Just put compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0' in your build.gradle file(App level)

Answer (score 0):

i came here becouse i had tha same ( i think) problem.
This happens to me becouse android Studio wanted to update gradle for some newer version.
As it updates in background i wanted to generate an app (signed).
So Studio i think waiting for next version of gradle to download , i thought it was freezed and forcely stopped the process.
That act is the cause of the later problem becouse it corrupts some of my images under

> /res/drawable/hddpi...etc

**The** **solution was**

> to remove them (only the corrupted) restarting Android Studio and all
>   works like supposed to.

bellow is the corrupted image..
tip for fast indicating the corrupt images..(just look in thumbnail windows make for selected image , every time..)
Any way.. this for someone will be at this situation.
[image]